# Many to Many Relationship in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 - How to?

Tags: many-to-many, entity-relationship, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I'm working on a MS CRM server for a project at my university.

What I'm trying to do is to let the user of the CRM to tag some contacts, I thought of creating an entity to archive the tags an to create an N:N relationship between the tag entity and the contact one.
I've created and published the new entity and the relationship, but I don't know how to add a lookup field to the contact form, so that the user can see the tags related to one contact and add a new one.

Can anyone help me?

If you couldn't understand what I'm trying to do tell me, I'll reformulate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to write up an answer, but realized you were talking about 4.0 and I've only done it in 3.0.

I was able to find a screen cast about the new many to many feature in 4.0 however

http://www.philiprichardson.org/blog/post/Titan-Many-to-Many-Relationships.aspx